# Android - Skipped frames message from Choreographer

Tags: android, frame, menubar

In my application, I am receiving many Skipped frames message from Choreographer. So, I started checking one by one, and I was very much surprised to see 76 Skipped frames when I just click on the default menu button on my MainActivity page.

To find out the problem, I commented out almost all methods from my MainActivity java, and still I am getting 77 Skipped frames! There is not Skipped frames message during loading of MainActivity page, it just pop up whenever I click on menu button on top-right corner.

Can anybody please help?

**EDIT:** I noticed that method onCreateOptionsMenu is only called one time during first creation. After that it never get called. So, which method is responsible for showing the menu, and why is this delay?

Below are the current active part of my code:

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static int CURR_BOOK_ID = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //populateData(0,0);
        //ActivitySwipeDetector swipe = new ActivitySwipeDetector(this, (SwipeInterface) this);
        //RelativeLayout swipe_layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainll);
        //swipe_layout.setOnTouchListener(swipe);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Menu:**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:icon="@drawable/settings"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/importexport"
        android:orderInCategory="50"
        android:icon="@drawable/import_export"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/importexport"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/deleteentry"
        android:orderInCategory="40"
        android:icon="@drawable/delete_entry"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/deleteentry"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/editentry"
        android:orderInCategory="20"
        android:icon="@drawable/edit_entry"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/editentry"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/addentry"
        android:orderInCategory="30"
        android:icon="@drawable/add_entry"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/addentry"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/showlist"
        android:orderInCategory="10"
        android:icon="@drawable/show_list"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/showlist"/>

</menu>
```

**Menu Button (that triggers the message):**
[image]

Comment: Is it a full code of your activity class? In order, when you press this button onCreateOptionsMenu not calling, as I remember. At this moment android calls OnPrepareOptionMenu

Comment: right now, not a single extra line is inside Activity class, everything is commented by /* .. */ ........... also, I never had any OnPrepareOptionMenu in my class :-s

Comment: ok, try to track how many time needs for getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
 You can simply achive that whith code like that: 
long time = System.currentTimeMillisec();
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
Log.e("time", (System.currentTimeMillisec - time)+" ");

Comment: it outputs 9, but during creation of main activity. But when I click on menu button, it does not show any thing. That means it does not go inside onCreateOptionsMenu every time I click on it. So, which function is controlling that ? confused ..