# android - Which method is called when I click on Menu button

Tags: android, menu

If I click on the menu button at the top-right corner (that drops down all the menus defined in menu.xml), which method is called? As apparently, onCreateOptionsMenu is only called during the creation of the activity UI.

I am receiving choreographer alert for skipped frame during menu expansion, that's why i need to know that - [Android - Skipped frames message from Choreographer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143861/android-skipped-frames-message-from-choreographer)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        Log.d("check","accessed");
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

WHEN I CLICK THIS: [image]

Comment: apparently it's not because Log.d("check","accessed"); is executed only one time (during creation of the thread)

Answer (score 1):

Following method is called:

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
```

Comment: I think onOptionsItemSelected is called when I select an option. but I need to know if I just click on menu icon (not any option) that drops down all the options, then which method is called?

Comment: Ok sorry checkout this method  public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item)

Comment: thanks, the method name suggests that it should be the one. But in my whole activity class, I don't have this method, but still my menu is working !! how? I am receiving choreographer alert for skipped frame during menu expansion, that's why i need to know that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143861/android-skipped-frames-message-from-choreographer

Comment: This method is help to detect if menu is expanded. It has nothing to do with your working of your menu.

Comment: but i dont have this method defined in my whole class!! frm where it is coming from? is it something internal or so?

Comment: You need to implement MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener listner in your activity.

Answer (score 0):

You may get the answer but I am posting this answer If someone needed. I have recently faced this problem then solved by this method. What actually this method does, whenever you click on menu icon this method called.

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuOpened(int featureId, Menu menu) {
    return super.onMenuOpened(featureId, menu);
}
```