# Android Lots of skipped frame errors

Tags: android, eclipse, performance-testing

I have finished my initial project but facing 2 issues while finalizing. If you kindly show me light

1) I am receiving lots of skipped XXX frame errors from Choreographer. I started looking one by one, then I realized some of them most probably have nothing to do with my code. For example, I explained here [Android - Skipped frames message from Choreographer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143861/android-skipped-frames-message-from-choreographer).

So, How can I know which LogCat choreographer messages I should be focusing on? Again, I am receiving lots of them, so it is very tough to check one by one which are real.

2) In my whole project, I only have one warning when I open and close menu tree without choosing any option. However, I guess it is also problem with emulator [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15175352/1951418).

I am using Eclipse as my emulator.

Any kind of advice is highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: It looks like you have 2 problems, that allready have questions up on stackoverflow. what is it exactly you want with this topic then?

Comment: For Q.1, there was not a single reply hence I presume that is not normal and probably due to my emulator. So I want to know whether there is any better way to check (like how to check in real device and still getting the choreographer messages)? For Q.2, again, it was not surely answered, one person just assumed/guessed .. so I want to have the advice that should I ignore that?

Comment: If you have a lot of code in the OnCreate method of your first activity, this will slow down the choreographer and throw those errors. Make sure you don't have any unnecessary code in there.

Comment: But even with almost nothing inside onCreate and inside class, I am getting the messages. Is there anyway I can check in some other way to reconfirm? (if you have some time, please check my example in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143861/android-skipped-frames-message-from-choreographer)

Answer (score 1):

A lot of skipped frames (probably) means you are doing too much calculations in the UI thread. If you are doing a lot of calculations, consider moving them into another thread, which might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the Choreographer outputs onto the Logcat view, using this filter expression :

**tag:^((?!Choreographer).*)$**